# When Cell is writen put the time and not update more

Tags: excel, function

What I'm trying to do, is a database, and a table for when a car or a person enters, I just put the name or the license plate and my database gives me the info I need.
That is done.
But I want to make that the most automatize like: When A4 have a "P" or a "C" it will give me the hour in E4 and doesn't change more.
So when I click in the button "Guardar Entrada" it will put the data in the table below and stay there without anyone changes it.
I have used the now() with if: `=IF(OR(A4="C";A4="P");NOW();"")`, but every time I put something in A4 the time changes even when they are already in other cell.

My work so far:
[image]
    {Sub InserirBD()
        '
        ' InserirBD Macro
        '

```
    '
    Range("A4:G4").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Rows("6:6").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("A4:G4").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
Sub Ir_p_ExpedienteEntradas()
'
' Ir_p_Expediente Macro
'

'
    Sheets("Expediente Entradas").Select
    Range("A4").Select
End Sub

Sub Ir_p_ExpedienteSaidas()

    Sheets("Expediente Saidas").Select
    Range("A4").Select
End Sub
Sub Ir_p_BD()
'
' Ir_p_BD Macro
    Sheets("Base de Dados").Select
    Range("A4").Select
End Sub
Sub Inserir_EXP()
' Macro para inserir expediente

Range("A4:J4").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("A6:J6").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Range("A4:C4").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.ClearContents
End Sub}
```

Thanks

Comment: `NOW` is always changing, if you want to keep the value static, you will have to remove the function, one option being through copying and pasting as value. Another would be to use VBA to insert the value directly as opposed to a function.

Comment: @Tiw Since I'm learning to code in really short time and on the go:

{Dim MyTime As String

MyTime = Format(Time, "Long Time")

If Cell("A4") = "C" Or Cell("A4") = "P" Then
    Range("E4").Value = MyTime
End If}